# Eigenvalues of the Frobenius-Perron Operator

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Say I have a map ${\bf X}_n = {\bf F}({\bf X}_{n-1})$, ${\bf X_n} \in \mathbb{R}^N$.
The Frobenius-Perron operator $L$ transfers the probability measure in phase space according to the dynamics defined by the map, ${\bf F}$. That is, 
$L \mu_n = \mu_{n+1}$, where $\mu_n$ is the probability distribution in phase space at time $n$. $\mu_0$ is the initial distribution.

We know that the map has an invariant measure $\mu$. In other words, $L$ has an eigenvalue 1 with eigenfunction $\mu$. My question is: under what conditions,
(on ${\bf F}$ and $L$) will $L$ have an at most countably infinite set of eigenvalues?  I know that compact operators on separable Hilbert spaces can be shown to have at most countably infinite set of eigenvalues but I have never studied the space of measures formally and am not sure how to think about this.

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's play on a compact manifold, e.g. $M = \mathbb T^d$, the $d$-dimensional torus.

Let's also play with slightly nicer measures, as in some sense the class of Borel measures is quite large. In applications, one usually works with a subset of suitable measures, e.g. absolutely continuous measures with some regularity assumption on the density.

Let's assume that $F$ is a local diffeomorphism, so that $\mu_1, \mu_2, \cdots$ are absolutely continuous if $\mu_0$ is. Let $\rho_n$ be the density of $\mu_n$. Then, $\rho_{n+1}$ is given as $\mathcal L \rho_n = \rho_{n+1}$, where $\mathcal L$ is the (Ruelle) transfer operator:
$$
\mathcal L \rho(x) = \sum_{y \in F^{-1} x} \frac{\rho(y)}{|\det dF_y|} \, .
$$
(you should check this using the change of variables formula!)

When $F$ is *expanding* ($\| dF^n_x v\| \geq C \lambda^n$ for some $C > 0, \lambda > 1$ and at all points $x \in M$), $F$ spreads mass out and so the transfer operator $\mathcal L$ has a *smoothing effect* on densities. Formally, one often works with the space $\operatorname{Lip}$ of Lipschitz-continuous functions on $M$. One can show, then, that regarded as an operator on $\operatorname{Lip}$ that $\mathcal L$ is *quasicompact*, i.e., there exists some $\gamma \in [0,1)$ such that the spectrum of $\mathcal L$ outside of $\{ z \in \mathbb C : |z| \leq \gamma \}$ consists of finitely many eigenvalues (sometimes called Ruelle-Pollicot resonances).

I should note: quasicompactness of the transfer operator can be used to obtain exponential decay of correlations: this is perhaps the most significant application of these ideas.

For compactness, [see the paper of Grundlach and Latushkin,](https://faculty.missouri.edu/~latushkiny/preprints/ruelle.pdf) who obtain an explicit formula for the radius of the essential spectrum of $\mathcal L$ in the above setting with respect to successively finer spaces of densities.

Lastly: the expanding case is the simplest to describe. Roughly speaking, $\mathcal L$ has a tendency to 'pile up' mass along directions where $dF$ is contracting (to see this in action: suppose $F$ has an attracting fixed point somewhere and watch mass accumulate to a Dirac delta measure at that fixed point!). As a result, for more general $F$ one usually works with specialized Banach spaces of measures. See, for example, the book *Decay of Correlations* by Baladi.

Comment: If you're interested, Vaughn Climenhaga has a few blog posts on spectral gaps for transfer operators: https://vaughnclimenhaga.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/spectral-methods-in-dynamics/

Comment: Thank you very, very much! I asked the question with decay of correlations in mind - so your answer was more than what I was hoping for. Thanks also for the references - the book by Baladi looks very illuminating!    I have a fundamental question: is the joint density defined when we have an SRB measure on the attractor? Since the SRB measure has a density only along unstable directions, can we still use the equation for the transfer operator that you have written (I understand how it is derived when we have a density).

Comment: ^I am not specifically looking at diffeomorphisms. Let's say I am interested in any system that has an invariant measure that can be classified as an SRB measure.